# How convert content://0@ to accept uri - android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using from `android.intent.action.SEND` in my app for share image, video, pdf, etc... in my app like bellow:

```
    <activity
        android:name="aa.aa.aa.main.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
            android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And I get it in `onNewIntent` of `MainActivity` like bellow:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (intent != null) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();
        if (action != null && type != null) {
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
        }
    }
}
```

But it is always `null`:

```
Uri uri = intent.getData();
```

After this problem I use from bellow way:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if (intent != null) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();
        if (action != null && type != null) {
            String receivedUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM).toString();
        }
    }
}
```

And it get me bellow url:

```
content://0@media/external/images/media/10059
```

But when I load it in `glide` like bellow, I can't see any image:

```
URI uri = Uri.parse(receivedUri);
GlideApp
  .with(context)
  .asBitmap()
  .load(uri)
  .fitCenter()
  .into(object : SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
      override fun onResourceReady(
            resource: Bitmap,
            transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
    ) {
       imagePreview.setImageBitmap(resource)
      }
 })
```

How can I get `URI`?

Comment: you need to setup fileprovider.

Comment: @Karan Mer. How? Get me code please. Thank's

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider